# Test an hypothesis significantly

Tags: statistics, anova, usage-statistics

How can I test the hypothesis that the execution time of an 
algorithm is not exponentially, with respect to the size of the data.

For exaple, I have the sample:

[n time(s)] = {[02 0.36], [03 1.15], [04 2.66], [05 5.48], [06 6.54], [07 11.22], [08 12.87], [09 16.94], [10 17.59]}

where n is the size of the data. I want to proof significantly that the time does not grow exponentially with respect to the data.

What should be the hypotheses H0, H1.

Should I use anova or f-test? How do I apply it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this should be a comment, not an answer, but it got too long.

You probably need to learn a bit more about the rationale behind hypothesis testing. I suggest that you start with some online material such as this: http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/hypothesis-testing.aspx, but you may also need to look at some books on statistics. Your question, as it is now, cannot be answered because you can never "use statistics to prove something". Statistics will only tell you what is *probable*. So you cannot prove that the execution time does not grow exponentially. From you sample data, it **really** looks that it's not exponential. As a matter of fact, it **really** looks to be linear, so the growth is *probably* linear:

[image: Linear model of data]

The code for generating this image in R is:

```
> n <- 2:10
> time <-c(0.36, 1.15, 2.66, 5.48, 6.54, 11.22, 12.87, 16.94, 17.59)
> model.linear <- lm(time ~n) # LM = Linear Model, time ~ a*n + b
> plot(time ~ n)
> lines(predict(model.linear)~n, col=2)
```

Do you need statistics to show that this linear model is a good fit? I hope you don't.